# 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts in SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, email, ssl, smtp, smtp-auth

I send emails using  SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE app, with those properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=calzada@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=***OBSCURED***
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.propertirs.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false
```

everything was fine until I tried to send an email with this result:

```
The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct the recipient to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaTemp b133sor4470647wmd.14 - gsmtp
```

after that error I got this error when sending emails:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. b54sm8636925ede.58 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Assuming the password you had in your original edit was real, go change it immediately, if you can.

Comment: thanks, it was not real :-)

Comment: Haha, ok cool. I saw it and had a small panic attack for you. :)

Comment: How did you solve the second error? Too many login attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have sent too many mails. Check limitations with smtp service.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Comment: Not mail sending related.. I guess it has more to do  with authentication attempts instead..