# Mail sending issue in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, gmail, smtp-auth

I've setup a Java mail code in my application which sends email, used spring-mail. Suddenly I'm getting this error.

```
o.s.b.actuate.mail.MailHealthIndicator   : Mail health check failed

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. s189-20020a1f5ec6000000b0034e6f1fd03bsm1688226vkb.5 - gsmtp
```

What could be the exact cause of this and how can I resolve it? The gmail account being used is a simple one and not an organisation one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578465/454-4-7-0-too-many-login-attempts-in-springboot-2-1-4-release

Comment: @Mansi It does for the login attempts part but what about health check issue? Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you want to send email in Java:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void sendMail(String recepient) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Preparing to send email");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        //  properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        String myAccountEmail = "yourmail";
        String password = "your passsword";
        //nebamhselddwspis
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(myAccountEmail, password);
            }
        });
        Message message = prepareMessage(session, myAccountEmail, recepient);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Messaggio successfully sent");

    }

    private static Message prepareMessage(Session session, String myAccountEmail, String recepient) {

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myAccountEmail));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recepient));
            message.setSubject("Prova™");
            message.setText("Ciao,ci sono delle nuove attività su Casotto,  \n effettua il Login per dare un'occhiata e prenotarti!");
            return message;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendEmail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Remember to generate password app if you have two factor auth on Google Mail.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Does this code still work after the removal of less secure apps?

Comment: Maybe yes, i have two factor auth and worked, but you have to generate password as I said before.

Comment: Google has been unclear if using an apps password will work without less secure apps.  I thought they would expect everyone to move to Xoauth2.  Glad its still working for you.  Guess we will know for sure May 30, 2022.

Comment: I dont know, I created only app password via Google and i have 2 factors auth and it works.